# Minion Pro activate small caps for greek

Tags: fontspec, small-caps

According to otfinfo, greek small capitals are supported in Minion Pro.

```
otfinfo --script=grek -f MinionPro-Regular.otf

...
smcp    Small Capitals
...
```

yet the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}
\textsc{Small Capitals}

\textsc{Πεζοκεφαλαία}
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image]

What option should I pass to fontspec in order to have small capitals with Minion Pro for greek Glyphs?

Comment: I found a reference which suggested that Minion Pro has no greek small caps.

Comment: @Ulrike Thank you. Can you give a link or something? According to `otfinfo` there must be small caps. Also on libre office there are small caps, but I don't know if they are real or not.

Comment: I simply ran a google search with "Minion pro greek small caps" and got some hits which suggested that there is a problem but nothing so decisive that I would absolutly rely on it. I also tried to activate the small caps with lowlevel commands and it didn't work so I don't think that fontspec is the problem. Try to find another font for comparision.

Comment: @Ulrike Ι checked with fontforge and I didn't find anything related with greek small caps... Propably you are right and the greek small caps are not implemented.

Comment: It seems so... I tried to `\addfontfeature{Script=Greek, Letters=SmallCaps}` too and the result is the same

Comment: @pmav99: what `otfinfo` is telling you is that the font designer have registered a `smcp` feature for `grek` script, but this tells nothing about existent of smalcap glyphs for any given character, and it is common practice to register features to all scripts supported by the font, even if only Latin is actually covered by the feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the appropriate glyphs are not available. Using the [MyFonts site for Minion Pro](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/minion/) it is possible to do a 'live test' with text of your choice and picking small caps:
[image].

As you can see, the result is identical to the TeX result - no small caps.